# jQuery .load issue when switching content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[Tristann.tk](http://tristann.tk/)
On this site click About me and then click back to Home, and then try switching the pages at the bottom, It doesn't change. Why?

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".page_links .page li").click(function(){
        $(".page_links .page li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});
        $(".posts").load("/includes/data.php?data=pages&page=" + this.className);
    });
    $(".navlist #about_me").click(function(){
        $(".navlist #home").css({'text-decoration' : 'none'});
        $(".navlist #about_me").css({'text-decoration' : 'underline'});
        $(".vsebina").load("/includes/data.php?data=about_me");
    });
    $(".navlist #home").click(function(){
        $(".navlist #about_me").css({'text-decoration' : 'none'});
        $(".navlist #home").css({'text-decoration' : 'underline'});
        $(".vsebina").load("/includes/data.php?data=home");
    });
    $(".navlist #home").css({'text-decoration' : 'underline'});
    $(".1").css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});
});
```

The divs are like that:

```
<div class="zunanji">
    <div class="glava">
        <div class="meni">
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li><a id="home" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="about_me" href="javascript:void(0)">About Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="vsebina">
        <? get_posts();
           get_pages();
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="stranska">
            <h2>Archive</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 2 PHP functions return the 5 posts at the start and the page numbers at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to rebind those events after every `load` because the `page_link`s are being replaced. An easier and cleaner way to do it is to use event delegation. The best way is to use [`$.fn.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which performs better and is less buggy than `$.fn.live`. Also, since the `load` will replace the `page_links` you have to do the `background-color` stuff in a callback:

```
$(".vsebina").on('click', '.page_links .page li', function(){
    var $page = $(this); // save the page link that was clicked
    var path = "/includes/data.php?data=pages&page=" + this.className;

    $(".posts").load(path, function(){
        $(".page_links .page li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $page.css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});            
    });
});
```

This binds a click event to the `.vsebina` container and checks to see if the clicked item was a page link. If it was, it will fire your handler. This way, even if the content is replaced, your handler will run.

[Read more about `$.fn.on` vs `$.fn.live` vs `$.fn.delegate` vs `$.fn.bind` here](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html)

Comment: how can I do that in a pretty way?

Comment: Event delegation is the preferred way of doing this. See my edit for details on how to use `$.fn.on`

Comment: I think the way that Johann described it is easier. Thanks for the reply tho.

Comment: you're welcome. Yes, `live` is definitely easier, but it is slower and can be buggy. Check out the article at the bottom of my answer if you are curious. It looks like you are just working on a simple, personal page, so you should be fine, but keep this in mind for the future!

Comment: Aham, I know what you mean now, this method is definately better.
Thanks. :D

Comment: I can't get the background of the page buttons to change the bg, tried putting it into this function after load, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's due to the same issue: you are making changes on content that will be replaced as soon as the load completes. Putting the call to `.css()` after the `load` won't make a difference because `load` happens asynchronously. This is why you must pass a callback method that will be executed when `load` is finished.

Comment: I'd also recommend that you make a class to handle the coloring of the page links. So, in your css, you could add a rule like `.page_links .active { background-color: #a5cdfa; }` and then in your js you would just add/remove that class as needed. That would be much faster and cleaner than adding/removing inline styles like you are doing.

Comment: How can I "pass a callback method"? I didn't find any useful information on google.

Comment: I'm doing it in the code in my answer. It just means you pass a function to the `load` method that will be executed when the loading has finished. All of jQuery's ajax methods (load, get, post, ajax, etc.) provide ways for you to do this. Even animations like `fadeIn` let you pass a function that will be called when the fading is done.

Comment: Mhm, found it just now on the jquery website :D. Changed so it doesn't apply the style directly, using classes now. You were right, everything looks simpler until now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your click events are getting disconnected when you load new content.  Change your page nav code to use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method:

```
 $(".page_links .page li").live('click',function(){
        $(".page_links .page li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});
        $(".posts").load("/includes/data.php?data=pages&page=" + this.className);
  });
```

Comment: But the bg of the page button doesn't turn back,     $(".1").css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});

Comment: You'll need to call that each time you reload the #home content.  So, add that line  inside the #home click event.